# Why Doesn't gravity or text alignment of vertical textview work?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

Recently I've had to create a vertical textview. after searching I found out inherited class from textView  that other people used. it is worked good. but I realize some problems. this class does not work with any gravity or alignment attributes. I tried to set gravity or layout direction to RTL but it does not work either. I use Persian language and this problem gets too bad. the thing I need set my texts in center of vertical textview.
p.s: I have to use "android: gravity =" bottom " to rotating text 90 degree according to the condition in class.

so the vertical class :

```
class VerticalTextView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : AppCompatTextView(context, attrs) {
    private val topDown = gravity.let { g ->
        !(Gravity.isVertical(g) && g.and(Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM)
    }
    private val metrics = BoringLayout.Metrics()
    private var padLeft = 0
    private var padTop = 0

    private var layout1: Layout? = null

    override fun setText(text: CharSequence, type: BufferType) {
        super.setText(text, type)
        layout1 = null
    }

    private fun makeLayout(): Layout {
        if (layout1 == null) {
            metrics.width = height
            paint.color = currentTextColor
            paint.drawableState = drawableState
            layout1 = BoringLayout.make(text, paint, metrics.width, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 2f, 0f, metrics, false, TruncateAt.END, height - compoundPaddingLeft - compoundPaddingRight)
            padLeft = compoundPaddingLeft
            padTop = extendedPaddingTop
        }
        return layout1!!
    }

    override fun onDraw(c: Canvas) {
        //      c.drawColor(0xffffff80); // TEST
        if (layout == null)
            return
        c.withSave {
            if (topDown) {
                val fm = paint.fontMetrics
                translate(textSize - (fm.bottom - fm.descent),0f)
                gravity= Gravity.CENTER //never works
                textAlignment= TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER //never works
                rotate(90f)
            } else
            {
                translate(textSize, height.toFloat())
                rotate(-90f)
            }
//            translate(padLeft.toFloat(), padTop.toFloat())
            makeLayout().draw(this)
        }
    }
}
```

my xml layout:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:textDirection="rtl"

            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:background="@color/primaryColor"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/IVPlace"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/IVPlace"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            >

            <nima.mythird.simpleloginregister.utils.VerticalTextView
                android:id="@+id/TVNameViewPLace"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="متن تست"

                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:elevation="2dp"
/>

            <nima.mythird.simpleloginregister.utils.VerticalTextView
                android:id="@+id/TVِDistance"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="  123 "
                android:textDirection="rtl"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                />



        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Current result:

[image]

Comment: What is your expectation? I mean how you like to align text. PS: `TextView` is even more flexible.

Comment: @Udhayarajan there are 2 textviews . the texts are not aligned. now it is like Left To Right. I want that texts to be in middle of that 2 textviews.

Answer (score 1):

Your custom *TextView* takes over the layout and the drawing of the text. It is in the standard layout and drawing of the view that the text alignment properties to adjust the view are made, specifically in `onDraw()`. Here is [one place](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java;l=8017;drc=master;bpv=0;bpt=1) in *TextView.java* where gravity is used.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  

...

    if ((mGravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) != Gravity.TOP) {
        voffsetText = getVerticalOffset(false);
        voffsetCursor = getVerticalOffset(true);
    }
    canvas.translate(compoundPaddingLeft, extendedPaddingTop + voffsetText);

...
```

Since your code doesn't call through to the *onDraw()* super, gravity has no effect. You probably can't call through to the super, anyway, since it will do things you don't wish to do.

You will have to handle text alignment yourself in the custom view. I suggest that you take a look at *TextView.java* to see how you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below line for all your textview.

android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```

Comment: tnx but it is not worked. it seems this property does not work with vertical textview. I have to use "https://github.com/yoog568/VerticalTextView" or  " https://github.com/yoog568/VerticalTextView/blob/master/src/com/yoog/widget/VerticalTextView.java ". but this customized class does not support some feature like "android:ellipsize="end" ".